# Grails, ORM, Quartz, Jobs,

Tags: hibernate, grails, orm, quartz-scheduler

I'm working with Grails 3.0.12, I'm using Quartz to execute a job, what I try to do now is to send an email every time (In this case every 5 seconds). I have email Service in my Services folder. This is my code:

```
class EnviaCorreosJob{
NotifierService notificar
Integer diasParaCorreo = 30

static triggers = 
{
    cron name: 'myTrigger', cronExpression: "*/5 * * * * ?"
}
def group = "MyGroup"
def description = "Example job with Cron Trigger"
def fechaHoy = new Date()

def execute()
{   
    println "------------------ Running every 5 seconds -------------------"

    def queryAgenda = Agenda.where 
    {
        inicio_cita <= (fechaHoy + diasParaCorreo)
    }
    def listaAgenda = queryAgenda.list()
    println "----------------------Dates list : " + listaAgenda

    log.info "listaAgenda: " + listaAgenda
    log.info "listaAgendaTamaño: " + listaAgenda.size()

    listaAgenda.each
    {
        agenda ->

        println "it's inside"

        mailService.sendMail
        {
            to "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
            subject "hello"
            body "hello"
        }
    }
}
}
```

I tried to make an instance of Service class to call mailService.sendMail but didn't work.

Thanks so much for your help. :)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are trying to use the mail plugin in your job but you haven't injected the mail service into your Job.

Add:

```
def mailService
```

To your class and it will be injected and useable. More on service injection can be found here https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/single.html#dependencyInjectionServices

More info on configuring and using the mail plugin is here - https://grails.org/plugins.html#plugin/mail

Comment: I've added **def mailService** , but now this is the error

org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method sendMail() on null object

Comment: Do you actually have the mail plugin defined in your `build.gradle` ? Can you show a complete example?

Comment: Yes, but was my mistake, you're right, I move some code and **def mailService** was correct thing I should put first.
Thanks so much. :)

Comment: I tried, but my "reputation" isn't enough to qualify your answer, but it works. :)
Thanks for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I have done something similar, sending emails from files within a directory using the @Scheduled annotation.

```
EmailService emailService

static boolean lazyInit = false 
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000L, initialDelay = 2000L) 
void executeEveryFourtyFive() {


dire = new File(configfilepath)
dire.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { fileEmail ->
listEmail << fileEmail
}

listEmail.each {
filepath = it.path
sourceFolder = new File(filepath) 

   if (sourceFolder.exists()){  
    String fileContents = new File(filepath).text
       def emailaddress = emailaddress

    def emailmessage = message
    def emailtitle = title

    def emailsubject = subject
    def emailfrom = emailfrom
 emailService.send(emailaddress,emailmessage,emailsubject...)
   }
 }
 }catch(Exception exc){
      exc.printStackTrace()
    }
  }else{
   println "++++++++++email service off++++++++++"
 }
 }
```

And then I have my emailService to do the rest. Hope it helps someone.